# When using Kubernetes Do i need to still use Containers for Oracle?

Tags: kubernetes

When using Rubbernecks do I need to still use Containers for Oracle?

Here is my case, I am designing microservice architecture for my application using kubernetes.

I have deployed all my front-end, middleware and back-end services in different containers.

But for the data layer, I am not sure is it the right way to deploy Oracle in a container, as the database cannot be scaled horizontally. And if I want to scale the data container vertically in Kubernetes, How can I do that?

Generally how this is handled in the Kubernetes world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to come to terms with what you want/expect.

You *can* run a database on kube, specialy since StatefulSets. You might want to look into PersistentVolumes and PersistentVolumeClaims as well.

You *can* connect from kube services to an off cluster database managed in traditional way.

Which way you choose depends largely on what are you projects constraints and team experience or expected solution portability between envs and level of automation you want/have around it.